# TFS 2015 Link test cases with CI build

Tags: tfs, automated-tests

Is it possible to link the test results from a build defined in vNext with automated test cases defined in TFS?

Here is our current set-up:

- TFS 2015 with update 1 (on premises)
- User stories defined, acceptance criteria defined as scenarios which translate to test cases.
- Code set-up with automated tests using MsTest (via SpecFlow)
- Tests in MsTest linked with test cases using the test case manager tool:
  `> tcm testcase /import /collection:http://tfs:8080/tfs /teamproject:project1 /syncsuite:121 /storage:Domain1\Domain1.Spec\bin\Debug\Domain1.Spec.dll`
- 2 builds created with vNext:

  1. Continuous integration build where the `Visual Studio Test` build step used
  2. Periodic delivery build which runs heavier tests using the `Visual Studio Test using Test Agent` build step

The problem is that we do not see any link to the test case in the test results that were run for the builds.

Having this link would provide useful information like

- % of test cases running in CI build
- % of test cases running for a delivery build
- Run history for each automated test case with respect to the builds
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not test case related information in build result. But you can get test run result on how many tests are passed.

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw that, and even manual tests are reported in that result section if they are run through the test manager web interface. On top of that it can be quite nice if the test plan is created in such a way that its grouped by user story.  

It just feels like this is the last small link in a traceability report for continuous delivery set-up.

Comment: You may associate the test case work items when check-in, after build, you'll get Associated work items in build result.

Comment: That is an idea, although that will only show up for the first build after the commit. Subsequent builds will not have the same work item links.... At this stage the most likely solution will be creating a custom report somehow either through the TFS api or some reporting services.

Comment: Maybe another idea: is it possible to perform a query across work items and build results? Queries with such a join would allow us to add the charts we would like to the dashboard.

Comment: There is not such query across work items and build results by default. You may consider submitting a user voice here https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Comment: ok.. I raised my voice at: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12471294-queries-joining-work-items-and-build-test-results ... :D